# Does TCP client need open ports to connect to external server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, network-protocols

I'm very new to android developement with almost no background on network technologies. I've made simple TCP server in Java and TCP client in android. Everything is working inside my local network.

My question is if client can connect to Server on my external IP, through GSM network, where are all ports always blocked by mobile network operator, so only server would have forwarded ports to the global internet.

If this isn't possible I would be very grateful if you can suggest me good replacement for real time communication between android (through GSM intenet) and server (everything I found for real time communication was TCP / UDP protocol).

Thanks for replies ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can connect through open ports on your server from a cell network.  Otherwise a lot of Android apps out there simply wouldn't function.

My company uses a custom port when connecting to our demo servers for our smart phone apps.  Never had a bit of trouble on any providers in the US.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Unfortunately I can't vote up because I just joined forum.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your GSM operator allows outbound traffic, you need no ports open to connect to a remote server. When you try to establish a connection, the provider's NAT or NAT-like equipment will open a port temporarily for that one socket. It allows for outbound without letting inbound packets open connections.

If your GSM provider disallows *all* traffic, you're out of luck.